# after clicking on icon sidebar appears from right side

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i add a moving sidebar from right side after clicking on icon?
i mean it is supposed to work like hamburger
i tried to edit some hamburgers that i found in the internet but it went not so good
also if somebody could review my code would be nice :D
it is school project and im kinda new in html/css

```css
*{
    overflow:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;

}

html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
body{
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E98074, #D8C3A5, #E98074);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 5s ease infinite;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:100px;
}
/* #EAE7DC
#D8C3A5
#8E8D8A
#E98074
#E85A4F */
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    
    
    
}


.jp{
    width:50%;
    font-size:300%;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.gmd{
    width:50%;
    font-size:300%;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
a:hover{
    
    font-size:115%;
}
.current{
    color:#E85A4F;

}
p{
    color:#E85A4F;
}
li{
    color:#8E8D8A;
    text-align:justify;
    padding-left:33%;
  
}
input{
    background-color:#EAE7DC;
    border:none;
    color:#E85A4F;
    font-size:130%;
}
input:hover{
    font-size:145%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E85A4F;
}
h1{
    color:white;
    font-size:300%;
}
@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
i{
    font-size:2rem;
    position:relative;
    right:45%;
    cursor:pointer;

}
.fa-user-cog:hover{
    color:black;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Projekt</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fab7910dc7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>

        <main> 
      
        </div>
            <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
            <h1>Quizy</h1>
            <br><br><br>
        <div class="jp">
            <a href="test.php">Test</a>
        </div>
            
        <div class="gmd">
            <a href="question_one.php">Losowe pytanie</a>
        </div>
         </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please specify which part of your code doesn't work? I didn't see any JS code that would toggle the siderbar you mentioned.

Comment: everything is working but i dont know how to make this sidebar